Additional clauses in sentences


There are, I think, some grounds for optimism.
The dean, as you know, is totally opposed to the proposal.
The best solution, it seems to me, would be to readvertise the position.


I think these bold parts are sentence modifiers.
What do you think about my opinion?
And we can place this at the beginning of the sentences as well.
So shouldn't we consider these as sentence modifiers?

The first sentence doesn't make sense.

Aside: in the second sentence "opposed to the proposal" is verbally clumsy. Perhaps "against the proposal" would flow better. Also they would be better at the beginning or the end, instead of breaking the sentence in the middle. And in the third one: "I think . . ."

Sure, these parenthetical phrases provide some additional information about the speaker's relationship to the information in the statement.
Not everything in grammar is a "modifier". Here is a page about "sentence modifiers" https://www.grammarbook.com/blog/clauses-sentences/sentence-modifier/   The second looks like a good example of a sentence modifier.  In the first and third, the parenthetical phrase is actually the matrix clause and the rest of the sentence is subordinate to it.
If you rephrase 1 as "I think there are some grounds for optimism", you can see that "there are... optimism" is the subordinate clause in the matrix "I think {X}"
